# How to use OpenIddict validation handler for exchanging authorization code for a token and retrieving the stored token from a cookie?

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, openiddict

My question is actually two questions, but they are closely connected to one another, as I have a feeling I'm missing something very simple.

I have an OpenIddict auth server on ASP.NET Core (working just fine), I have an SPA with an ASP.NET Core WebAPI resource server working with this auth server just fine, the resource server using OpenIddict Validation handler (aka `services.AddOpenIddict().AddValidation()`). The SPA is using the Authorization Code Flow with PKCE - also without any troubles. The token gets sent via the Authorization: Bearer header, everything is like it should be.

Now I have a need to connect to this auth server ANOTHER service - which is NOT an SPA, but instead a generic MVC ASP.NET Core app. And I thought of this setup:

1. The client (aka the browser) requests the service server and gets redirected to the Auth server as per the Authorization Code Flow.
2. The client authenticates on the auth server, receives the Authorization Code and gets redirected to the service server.
3. The service server receives the AuthCode and internally exchanges it for an Access (and Refresh) token (without using the client), and as it receives them both sets on the client two cookies - a session one for the Access token, and a permanent one for the Refresh token (with a path restriction). I am using encrypted tokens, so no info leaking here.
4. The client send the cookies all subsequent requests, and the service validates them from the cookie (instead of the Authorization header) and it all goes well.

Now, I wanted to reuse the same stack as used for my SPA, aka `services.AddOpenIddict().AddValidation()`, but I can't find out how to:

1. Exchange the auth code for the token? Do I need to do it manually, or am I missing some crucial piece of information on how to use the validation handler? Even if I do request it manually or using some other library - how can I verify the received token manually with the help of the validation handler from OpenIddict?
2. <s>Validate the tokens from the cookie instead of the Authorization: Bearer header? Do I need to register an Event Handler (aka `opts.AddEventHandler<ProcessAuthenticationContext>(...)`, doing something similar to what is done [here](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/dev/src/OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore/OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers.cs))?</s> See comment below, I think I solved that question.

Maybe I am even missing something more, and I need to somehow make use of `services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie(...)` mechanism? If so, how do I make it work with `services.AddOpenIddict().AddValidation()`?

Or what I want can't be done with the help of OpenIddict validation handlers, and I just need to use something different? But if so, how do I decrypt the tokens then to use it with other OpenIDConnect libraries?

Comment: After extensive googling, I stumbled upon https://kevinchalet.com/2018/07/02/implementing-advanced-scenarios-using-the-new-openiddict-rc3-events-model/ and the last snipped of code actually solves my second question about how to retrieve the token from cookies. The first question is still open though - how do I exchange the AuthCode to a token - do I do it with smth else (what? Smth from there: https://github.com/IdentityModel ?) or the validation handler provides something for that?